# Is there a Universal Property for finitely generated rings?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finitely generated ring and $M$ a finite minimal generating set for $R$.

I'm looking for a theorem that states that a function $\varphi:M \rightarrow S$ extends to a unique ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \rightarrow S$. Does such a theorem exist? Or possibly a similar one? I am aware of the universal mapping property of groups and am looking for one analgous for rings.

Comment: Among commutative rings, for simplicity, this characterizes polynomial rings in several variables. For such a universal to exist, the elements in $M$ should not be “related” in any way. But in a generic finitely generated ring, such relations among the generators generally exist. You can't do it for general groups either: you get *free* groups, if you want that property to hold.

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense. I am actually trying to form a homomorphism between polynomial rings- is there a universal property for a homomorphism from a polynomial ring to itself?

Comment: I have actually found a fair bit of reading on this. I will link something if I find a clear result, but I should be able to manage by myself from now. Thanks!

Comment: @Daven [If you look, you will find.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Polynomial_Ring) Sounds like you're already underway... good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a universal property characterizes *free* objects (here, rings).

In the case of commutative rings, the property that a ring $R$ has a (finite) subset $M$ so that every map $M\to S$ (where $S$ is any commutative ring) uniquely extends to a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ is the same as saying that $R$ is a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ in $|M|$ indeterminates.

For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, any subset is a set of generators; on the other hand there is *no* ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

If two elements in $M$ satisfy a polynomial relation with integer coefficients, then also their images under $\varphi$ should satisfy the same relation in order that $\varphi$ *can* extend to a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to egreg for pointing out that such a theorem does not exist, however there is a theorem for polynomial rings that is similar to the one I was searching for. See lemma 21.3: http://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/12-13/Spring/18.703/l_21.pdf

This result can be extended to polynomial rings in multiple variables by induction.

Comment: ...and it remains true for infinitely many variables. It makes the polynomial ring R[x] the initial object among "pointed R-algebras"; you'll find this point of view reflected at ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Polynomial_Ring